# What's the best way to collaborate and distribute project and release documentation within an organization?

Tags: content-management

It's a continual problem: allow collaboration (and versioning) among developers who are creating project plans, requirements, functional specs, design docs and test plans.  Then, publish for others in the organization (IT, Customer Service, Technical Support) to use this information.

What systems are people using to track project documentation?  How do you roll up change information per release and present it to end users?

Comment: We use Subversion.  Currently, developers checkin documents in a variety of formats (I prefer HTML) and whole tree is published on the intranet.  Problems arise when we want to include non-developers and allowing searching.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if I would regard this as best, but... Sharepoint is what we use (mostly) it's pretty well integrated into Office for sharing docs (with check in and out), plus you can create Wiki's, document lists with RSS feeds etc it's....usable.

Comment: Sharepoint sounds like the best solution from my perspective.